# How can I pipe sed output to printf for formating?

Tags: sed, quoting, printf

I am using Tecplot to process wind tunnel data, but the input for Tecplot requires a specific format for variable specification; each variable is bracketed by double quotes `"Variable Name"`. The problem is getting the double quotes isn't easy. I found in one post that `printf ' "%s" '` will produce this effect. However, printf is rather finicky about what it will take as input. I've been unable to pipe the variables from my data file using a `sed` before the `printf` but, I found another post that noted using `printf ' "%s" ' $(sed ...)`. This construct worked but is only half of the solution to my problem. I now want to use the output of this `printf` in a substitution with `sed` to swap out a placeholder (XYZXYZXYZ) with the contents of the `printf ' "%s" ' $(sed ...)`. All I get is an unterminated `'s`:

```
sed s/XYZXYZXYZ/` printf ' "%s" ' $(sed -n 1,265p Run-0020) `/ ../../wt/wt-layout_A.dat
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command
```

How do I get the XYZXYZXYZ to be changed to the output of the printf as noted?

Comment: Could you write a real sample input line, and the output you are expecting to obtain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your `printf` command in double quotes. With the `$(…)` command substitution syntax and adding single quotes to your `sed` commands, it would be:

```
sed 's/XYZXYZXYZ/'"$(printf ' "%s" ' $(sed -n '1,265p' Run-0020))"/ ../../wt/wt-layout_A.dat
```

You can probably remove the first space character in your `printf` command changing it to `printf '"%s" '`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you are trying to replace a string with a multi-line output in `sed`. The replacement string may not have newline characters. They need to be encoded as `\n`

One workaround could be encoding newlines in your replacement string with an unusual character, then decoding them again - inbetween just add quotes where needed:

```
 sed \
   #replace newlines in input with END OF TEXT byte as separator
   #not using NUL byte as many shells ignore them
   #ignore newline on last entry
   -e "s/XXX/$(sed -n 1,265p RUNFILE | tr '\n' '\03' | sed 's/\x03$//' )" \
   #replace new separator by "<separator>", as well addin " at beginning and end of line
   -e 's/\x03/"\0"/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/'
   #reintroduce newlines
   -e 's/\x03/\n/g' LAYOUTFILE > OUTPUT
```

Sample input

```
$cat LAYOUTFILE
XXX

$cat RUNFILE
1
....
300

$cat OUTPUT
"1"
....
"265"
```

---

PS: ignoring the use of `printf` as all you need is double quotes around the strings.